# How to replace a file path using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to replace a file path such as "C:\Users\Bob\Documents\file.xlsx" to "C:\Users\Bob\Documents" only. What will be the regular expression to replace the 'file.xlsx' to empty. The file name can be anything with any extension like txt, xls, csv etc.

I'm unable to create the regex to replace the right group.

[Regex Self Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enrJo.png)

Comment: Try: `\\[a-zA-Z1-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z1-9]+$`

Comment: Thanks @luigigi. It's working

Comment: @luigigi Is there any way to use re.sub() by grouping? I mean by grouping '\Documents\file.xlsx' and replace 'file.xlsx' with null.

Answer (score 3):

You're not looking for regex here, you're looking for [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname).

```py
import os

....

path = r"C:\Users\Bob\Documents\file.xlsx"
os.path.dirname(path)
```

Output:

```py
'C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents'
```

Extra info: I highly recommend using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create cross platform compatible paths, instead of using a string directly.

Comment: Thanks for that info but I'm treating this path as a string only. So looking for regex expression only.

Comment: This solution works on strings as well - as I already demonstrated. Using regex for this is simply not a good idea @Mandeep